# No value accessor for form control with name: ''

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'sNo'

it is not finding formCOntrolName in my DOM

component side

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
 'sNo': new FormControl,
 'question': new FormControl,
 'options': new FormGroup({
   'op': new FormControl,
  })
    });
```

HTML side

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
      <div *ngFor="let data of currentQuestionsValue">
        <div *ngFor="let d of data.items ">
          <strong formControlName="sNo"> {{ d.sno }}). </strong>
          <span formControlName="question">{{ d.question}}</span>
          <div>
            <form formGroupName="options">
              <label *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(d.options)" formControlName="op">
                <input type="radio" name="option" [value]="d.options[key]">
                <span>{{ d.options[key] }}</span>
              </label>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't apply a `formControlName` directive to an `strong` tag. It must be applied on a form field tag (`select`, `input`, `textarea`) or a custom component that implements the `CustomValueAccessor` interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **`formControlName="sNo"`** on an input and not on a **`strong`**